# Zigbee coordinator offline in OpenHab2

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, openhab

I am running OpenHab2 version 2.4.0 on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian, I am trying to setup ZigBee to be able to connect to a smart sensor except I can’t get my ZigBee coordinator to come online, the coordinator has a Zwave and Zigbee feature and I have got the Zwave Thing to say online but I can’t get the Zigbee Thing online. The USB coordinator is a Nortek Security and Control USB. I am using PaperUI to configure the Things.

I checked the `lsusb`

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
>   Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:004b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
>   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 10c4:8a2a Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. 
>   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
>   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
>   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
>   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>   pi@raspberrypi:~ $

When I run `dmesg -T | grep tty` I get the following response

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg -T | grep tty
>   [Fri Mar 29 21:54:46 2019] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=0 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
>   [Fri Mar 29 21:54:46 2019] console [tty1] enabled
>   [Fri Mar 29 21:54:47 2019] 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
>   [Fri Mar 29 21:54:50 2019] usb 1-1.3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
>   [Fri Mar 29 21:54:50 2019] usb 1-1.3: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB1

The openhab.log is full of the following message about 20 times

> BaseThingHandler] - Handler EmberHandler of thing zigbee:coordinator_ember:6b3e0d22 tried updating channel tx_dat although the handler was already disposed.

It also has the following error

> 2019-03-29 21:28:50.732 [ERROR] [nal.common.AbstractInvocationHandler] - An error occurred while calling method 'ThingHandler.dispose()' on 'org.openhab.binding.zigbee.ember.handler.EmberHandler@1ea8355': null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.zsmartsystems.zigbee.app.discovery.ZigBeeDiscoveryExtension.extensionShutdown(ZigBeeDiscoveryExtension.java:96) ~[?:?]
>       at com.zsmartsystems.zigbee.ZigBeeNetworkManager.shutdown(ZigBeeNetworkManager.java:529) ~[?:?]
>       at org.openhab.binding.zigbee.handler.ZigBeeCoordinatorHandler.dispose(ZigBeeCoordinatorHandler.java:303) ~[?:?]
>       at org.openhab.binding.zigbee.ember.handler.EmberHandler.dispose(EmberHandler.java:128) ~[?:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:?]
>       at org.eclipse.smarthome.core.internal.common.AbstractInvocationHandler.invokeDirect(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:153) [102:org.eclipse.smarthome.core:0.10.0.oh240]
>       at org.eclipse.smarthome.core.internal.common.Invocation.call(Invocation.java:53) [102:org.eclipse.smarthome.core:0.10.0.oh240]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:?]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:?]
>   2019-03-29 21:28:50.757 [ERROR] [core.thing.internal.ThingManagerImpl] - Exception occurred while disposing handler of thing 'zigbee:coordinator_ember:0d3bf8d6': null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.zsmartsystems.zigbee.app.discovery.ZigBeeDiscoveryExtension.extensionShutdown(ZigBeeDiscoveryExtension.java:96) ~[?:?]
>       at com.zsmartsystems.zigbee.ZigBeeNetworkManager.shutdown(ZigBeeNetworkManager.java:529) ~[?:?]
>       at org.openhab.binding.zigbee.handler.ZigBeeCoordinatorHandler.dispose(ZigBeeCoordinatorHandler.java:303) ~[?:?]
>       at org.openhab.binding.zigbee.ember.handler.EmberHandler.dispose(EmberHandler.java:128) ~[?:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[?:?]
>       at org.eclipse.smarthome.core.internal.common.AbstractInvocationHandler.invokeDirect(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:153) [102:org.eclipse.smarthome.core:0.10.0.oh240]
>       at org.eclipse.smarthome.core.internal.common.Invocation.call(Invocation.java:53) [102:org.eclipse.smarthome.core:0.10.0.oh240]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:?]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:?]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:?]

My PaperUI settings for the Ember are

- Port: /dev/ttyUSB1
- Flow Control: Software(xon/xoff)
- Baud Rate: 57600

I have explored the openhab2 community forums for days following different suggestions but none work nor give a clear answer on how to fix this.